# Querying an Odoo many-to-many field using raw SQL

Tags: sql, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I want to display many-to-many field in report.

Currently my model is as follows:

```
from openerp.esv import orm, fields


class myClass(orm.Model):
    _name = 'my.Class' 
    _columns = {
        'teacher_id': fields.many2many('fci.staff','lgna_teacher','ids_lol',
                                       'teacher_ids','Observers'),
    }
```

And I want to display them using SQL select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my example below, I'm considering that `teachers` and `courses` have a many-to-many relationship: teachers can teach multiple courses and courses can be taught by multiple teachers.

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields

class Teachers(orm.Model):
    _name = 'teachers'

    name = fields.Char() 

class Course(rm.Model):
    _name = 'course'

    title = fields.Char()
    teacher_ids = fields.Many2many('teachers', 'teacher_course_rel', 'course_id',
                                  'teacher_id', string='Teachers')
```

Using SQL (either using [Odoo API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods) or your DBMS), you can query the junction table (or *cross-reference table*) `teacher_course_rel` to retrieve the needed columns from each table.

For instance, the query below retrieves all the teachers' names teaching the Physics course:

```
SELECT c.title, t.name
FROM teacher AS t
INNER JOIN teacher_course_rel AS tcr
    ON t.id = tcr.teacher_id
INNER JOIN course AS c
    ON tcr.course_id = c.id
WHERE c.title = 'Physics'
```

Please note that I have used an SQL `INNER JOIN` which returns rows from the two tables only when the conditions are met (i.e. the two `INNER JOIN` conditions and the `WHERE` condition). For your purposes, you may wish to use a [different type of join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) depending on the information you wish to retrieve from both your tables.